# How to Bind JSON data source to Dev Express DataGridView Itemsource property?

Tags: .net, mobile, devexpress, maui

I have json data as api response and I want to bind it to Itemsource property of Dev express Datagridview.

```
string json = "[{"prop1":"xxx1","prop2":"xxx2","prop3":"xxx3","prop4":"xxx4"},{"prop1":"yyy1","prop2":"yyy2","prop3":"yyy3","prop4":"yyy4"}]"
```

Since the json response can have different fields based on the api request, I cannot create strongly typed class and deserialize the response.

So as per above json there will be columns prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4 and its data will be 2 rows.

Things I have tried.

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json1);
```

It generates two blank rows (for two records) somehow not able to display row data.

Other things I have tried

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json1);
```

It generates two blank rows (for two records) somehow not able to display row data.

Answer (score 0):

Since the rows appears but no data displayed, its related to columns

set the `AutoGenerateColumnsMode` property to Auto may fix the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did tried your solution but it end up having 'Type' as column and two rows having 'Object' as value.